# How do you assign a function to a value in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Scala, how do you assign a function of a particular signature to an appropriately typed value?

```
def foo = println("foo")
def bar = println("bar")
val fnRef : ()=>Unit = //the function named foo or the function named bar
```

Comment: `val fnRef = () => foo` seems to work

Comment: @Destin Why don't you convert your comment to an answer? I'd accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I feel like an unforgivably-terrible person for submitting this as an official answer, I do so at the OP's request.

This problem can be solved like so:

```
def foo = println("foo")
val fnRef = () => foo
```

or, as some other brave soul said before deleting his answer:

```
def foo = println("foo")
val fnRef = foo _
```

The second is perhaps slightly preferable, <s>since mine (the former) is mildly hacky and actually creates a whole new function that simply calls the existing function when applied, whereas the latter is basically a partial/delayed application of the existing function</s> because, while semantically identical, the latter is more-idiomatic Scala (as Rex Kerr points out).

Comment: The latter is the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: @Destin: Note that `foo _` syntax is actually just sugar for what you call ‘mildly hacky’. Both statements evaluate to the same code in this case.

Comment: @Debilski Wow, thanks for that!  I was a bit surprised when scalac verified this for me just now.  I think it's worth noting, though, that the compiled code actually starts to differ a bit once these two approaches are extended to actual partial application (`((x: Int, y: Int) => superFoo(x, y))(1, _: Int)` produces different code than does `superFoo(1, _: Int)`).  Regardless, thank you.  I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Destin That’s not quite correct. Your first `superFoo` example does the same underscore expansion as the second one but additionally before that you wrap the call to `superFoo` in another function call. Unexpanded this would be equal to `(superFoo _)(1, _: Int)`. Your second example actually expands to `(x$1: Int) => superFoo(1, x$1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` and `bar` aren't functions, they are methods. You can't assign methods to a name, because methods aren't objects.