# How do you assign an instance method to a value in Scala?

Tags: scala

Related: [How do you assign a function to a value in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743958/how-do-you-assign-a-function-to-a-value-in-scala)

Given:

```
class Foo{
  def bar = println("bar")
  def bat = println("bat")
}
```

How do I create a `fnRef` such that it points to either `Foo.bar` or `Foo.bat`?

```
def deepFunction(foos : List[Foo], fnRef : ()=>Unit) = {
  foos.map(_.fnRef) //May call either bar or bat
}
```

Bonus: Is it possible to constrain the fnRef so that it's only methods of that signature within the Foo class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. :-) Instead you write your code in terms of first class functions. What makes this nice in Scala is that it will create a function literal from `_.method` that's of type `T => R`, where `T` is the type of the parameter, and `R` is the method's return type.

So, `_.bar` and `_.bat` would both make `Foo => Unit`:

```
scala> class Foo{
     |   def bar = println("bar")
     |   def bat = println("bat")
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> def deepFunction(foos: List[Foo], fn: Foo => Unit) {
     |   foos.map(fn)
     | }
deepFunction: (foos: List[Foo], fn: Foo => Unit)Unit

scala> deepFunction(List(new Foo, new Foo), _.bar)
bar
bar

scala> deepFunction(List(new Foo, new Foo), _.bat)
bat
bat
```

What's really nice about this approach is that you can use any function you want, not just member functions.

```
scala> def bam(f: Foo) { println("bam") }
bam: (f: Foo)Unit

scala> deepFunction(List(new Foo, new Foo), bam)
bam
bam
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a reference to a method as a function via partial application:

```
scala> val foo = new Foo
foo: Foo = Foo@5dc22e67

scala> val fun = foo.bar _
fun: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> fun()
bar
```

This also works with multiple parameter lists:

```
scala> class Bar { def bar(s: String, t: String) = println(s+t) }
defined class Bar

scala> new Bar().bar _
res0: (String, String) => Unit = <function2>
```

Comment: I can see how this works if, at the time of selecting `bar` or `bat`, I have all of my `Foo`s in hand. But wouldn't this require my `deepFunction` to take List[(Foo, ()=>Unit)]?

Comment: If you want to polymorphically select across them then sure, you need to use their type and accept a container of them. You don't necessarily need List though, you could for instance have varargs, or any other collection trait such as Seq, Iterable, Traversable, TraversableOnce etc.

Answer (score 1):

Methods aren't objects in Scala, you can't assign them to names.